# iphone Background Application

Tags: iphone

If we can build an application for upload to continue in the background even if the user exits the app in the same way that emails on the iPhone continue to send in the background? With my application attachment are going to take a long time to upload and I can see users browsing away and not uploading the file.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's called [task completion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). See the section called "Completing a Finite Length Task in the Background."